# Changing HMTL <input> value and applying it to the whole website using JS

Tags: javascript

I have to go through some diamonds with a lot of diffrent parameters on a daily basis.
I have to use this [website](https://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search).

I want to automate some steps in this process, using Javascript.
For that I have to change the values in the filter of the website via JS.

I tried this with (the price filter as example):

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("price-max-input")[0]
x.value = "4,500"
```

This changes the value in the price input field, but the filter doesn't apply the value. So the results don't change.
I also tried a few things by using .focus() but this also didn't work.

I hope someone of you have has an answer to this.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
With "filter", I am refering to this:
[filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yRxL.png)

My goal is to change some input fields in this filter and to apply the changed filter, so that I have a diffrent output of results. I hope that this clarifies my problem a little bit more.

Comment: Hello ThyR4n, welcome onboard! Would you please add some more information to your question, it's not very clear what do you intend with "filter" and what you're trying to accomplish.
As a new user, I suggest you to give a read to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it contains valid tips on how to ask questions here on stackoverflow... It's a good way to have an answer. Plus, if you ask a question with a more specific title, you will see a list of similar questions already asked,  maybe someone else already had a similar problem!

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I've changed the titel and added a disciption of the "filter".

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the `change` event programmatically. To do so, you need to instanciate a new event and dispatch it to the target element.

```
  // we get the element we want.
  var element = document.getElementsByName("price-max-input")[0];
  // we change it's value from the code.
  element.value = 30000;
  // we create a new event of type change,
  // this will trigger the change event listener bellow
  var event = new Event('change');
  // we dispatch the event on the selected element
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  // we blur the element to make sure everything is working properly.
  element.blur();
```

In the snippet bellow, there is a few things happening that you don't really need to take care of. The only thing you want is the code in the `triggerTheChangeEvent` function. This is the part were we trigger a change event from the code.

```js
function triggerTheChangeEvent() {
  // we get the element we want.
  var element = document.getElementsByName("price-max-input")[0];
  // we change it's value from the code.
  element.value = 30000;
  // we create a new event of type change,
  // this will trigger the change event listener bellow
  var event = new Event('change');
  // we dispatch the event on the selected element
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
  // we blur the element to make sure everything is working properly.
  element.blur();
}


// this code is only to create a working demo.
function changeTextValue() {
  var currentValue = document.getElementById('price-max-input').value;
  document.getElementById('currenTextValue').innerHTML = currentValue;
}

document.getElementById('triggerEventButton').addEventListener('click', triggerTheChangeEvent);

document.getElementById('price-max-input').addEventListener('change', changeTextValue);
```

```html
<h5>Try changing the input's value first, to see the text updating.</h5>
<input type="number" name="price-max-input" id="price-max-input" value="50"/>

<p>
  The current input value is.
  <span id="currenTextValue">50</span>
</p>


<button id="triggerEventButton">Trigger the change event! </button>
```

I've tried it on your website and it seams to change the value of the input. However, i'm not sure how to trigger a new search query.

One tip I can give you is to select an element and look at it's Event Listeners. This is how you can find out what is listener on which event and what does it trigger on the page. In chrome, it's in the devtools on the right toolbar, under the Event listenert tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind an `onChange` event handler to the input field, something like this may help:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByName("price-max-input")[0];
element.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('#currenTextValue').innerHTML = event.target.value;
});
```

This way, everytime the input field changes, the value in the input will change in the `currentTextElement` value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
What exactly do you mean with '#currenTextValue'?
Does this addEventListener always execute the function when I change the value of the input field with 'x.value = "4,500"'?

Comment: Hi @ThyR4n, "currentTextValue" is just an arbitrary id for the element you want to update the text value depending on the input field. Yes, once you execute the event listener it will bind the callback function to the event handler.